# Triggers for schema compatibility

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, triggers

Here's a good one I think. To start off with, I don't really know what a trigger is, which might become obvious now.

Are triggers good for maintaining backwards compatibility between database schemas?

Say I have a 1-to-many relationship in version 1. In version 2 this has been changed to a many-to-many. Would a properly implemented trigger be able to handle this so as to allow both versions to run on the same database? Is it a good idea?

Comment: You probably should, you know, read about triggers some first :)

Comment: I know. I would have, but I had a feeling I was asking a good question. Look at all the great answers I got! And everybody can read it!

Comment: @Martin consider that even an answer is irrelevant someone tried to help, you can downvote that's ok but stop being ironic and ungrateful for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this by utilizing a INSTEAD OF trigger for inserts, updates, and deletes on a view for the old version.  To make this more clear, let's consider the following example:

```
v1:
    A(id int, data varchar(30))
    B(id int, a_id int, data varchar(30))

v2:
    A(id int, data varchar(30))
    B(id int, data varchar(30), data2 varchar(20))
    AB(a_id int, b_id int)
```

First you would create a view to mimic the old version of the B table.  The tricky thing would be deciding on which of the AB relations to show to the old application.  One option would be to add a `primary_b` column of type `bit` to the `AB` table.  The view below uses this option

```
CREATE VIEW OldB AS 
    SELECT B.id AS id, AB.a_id AS a_id, B.data AS data,  
    FROM B INNER JOIN AB ON B.id = AB.b_id
    WHERE AB.primary_b = 1
```

Next you would create triggers on the view to handle inserts and updates.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger on OldB INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO B (id, data) SELECT id, data FROM inserted;
UPDATE AB SET primary_b = 0 WHERE b_id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted);
INSERT INTO AB (a_id, b_id, primary_b) SELECT a_id, id, 1 FROM inserted;

END 
GO
```

You would do something similar for instead of update, except that you would have to manage the change in A to B links by deleting and adding rows in AB.  I haven't checked this code out for errors yet, but I will in the next hour or so and post an update if needed.

Comment: I would like to award the checkmark to both answers, but since Ryan is the up-and-comer... As I've come to understand, there is still no easy way to do this. There would need to be a few more lines of code to fulfill Damien's requirements and there are probably many more gaps to fill.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing backwards compatibility is never straightforward. Imagine you have (version 1):

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    ID int not null primary key,
    ColA varchar(10) not null
)
CREATE TABLE T2 (
    ID int not null primary key,
    T1ID int not null,
    ColB varchar(10) not null,
    constraint FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY (T1ID) references T1
)
```

and now, for version 2, you wish to introduce:

```
CREATE TABLE T1_T2 (
    T1ID int not null,
    T2ID int not null,
    constraint PK_T1_T2 PRIMARY KEY (T1,T2),
    constraint FK_T1_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY (T1ID) references T1,
    constraint FK_T1_T2_T2 FOREIGN KEY (T2ID) references T2
)
```

And, I imagine from your question, that you're thinking activity on `T1_T2` could maintain the existing `T1ID` column in `T2`, for backwards compatibility.

It's certainly *possible* for this to happen, but you have a whole load of issues to address:

- Which `T1ID` value do you write to `T2` if there are multiple rows in `T1_T2`?
- If that row is deleted, what should happen to `T1ID` in `T2` - set NULL, pick another value?
- What if *all* rows matching `T2ID` are removed from `T1_T2`. Should the row from `T2` be deleted? Have `T1ID` set NULL?
- If a version 1 application updates `T1ID` in `T2` and no row exists in `T1_T2`, is this an error or should a new row be inserted?
- Will a version 1 application maybe assume it can delete a row from `T1` if no row in `T2` has that specific `T1ID`

I'm sure there are many more as well. You can work through all of these issues, but you'll never manage to perfectly simulate the old behaviours for 100% of the usage of the Version 1 schema.

---

If you can address all of the above issues, to your satisfaction, then yes, you can perform these maintenance tasks using triggers. As I say though, it won't be 100%, so you may still have to tweak the version 1 application(s) to fix some of their expectations.

Comment: Thanks for answering the general question. This would be my arbitrary, highly application dependent and hypothetical implementation. The last; Pick the last; Set T1ID to NULL; Error; No.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some combination of views and triggers.